# Is SQL parsing on topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Currently I have some problems which go into the direction of this SO question [Parsing SQL in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083/parsing-sql-in-net)

My feeling is, that more experts for such questions probably follow SO than DBA and that they possibly are boarderline.

Edit:

Obviously formatting and pretty printing of sql scripts require to some extend solutions based on parsing. I have little interest in parsing by if self, but I'm interested in those  depending fields.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to recommend leaving the parsing questions on SO, as it needs skills that aren't exercised in database design and administration.

Comment: I agree with re-guard to the specific question referenced. @drachenstern has a good answer if the question focus would have been slightly different.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree strongly. Language parsing is certainly a programming task, and a hard-core one at that.

Such questions do not fit here in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

My feedback on this is that because you're going to have to deal with more than just recognizing what words match what clauses, that this is a reasonable thing to post on this site. However, it depends how much of what you're having trouble with is programming related, and how much is database expertise specific.

Because anything of the level of accurately re-interpreting source is usually wizard level to begin with, I'm gonna vote yes. Bring it on over.

Comment: I agree that interpreting SQL is more than just a parsing problem, but the specific question referenced does not seem to focus on that aspect, therefore I think it should remain on SO.